pg_restore does not give back shell
I got a dump file.I'm trying to restore it but after it finished it does not give back shell and stucks.Is there any solution ?

What makes you think it finished?

after hours I checked dbs and they were all there.So I thought maybe after while It will finish but It was stuck where I left.

What OS and what version of pg_restore? Can you reproduce this by dumping and restarting an empty database?

Perhaps you could use pg_stat_activity to see what the pg_restore session is doing.

Please show the command line invocation with the options. It's plausible that pg_restore just waits for input and does nothing because of the options.
